# JavaFX .getProperties() in FXML

Tags: javafx, fxml

How can I move this to FXML?

```
hBox.getProperties().put("key", "value");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
<HBox>
    <properties key="value"/>
</HBox>
```

as in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#read_only_map_property_elements).

The variation

```
<HBox>
    <properties>
        <key>
            <String fx:value="value"/>
        </key>
    </properties>
</HBox>
```

might be useful if the value you want is a more complex object:

```
<HBox>
    <properties>
        <character>
            <String fx:value="Arthur Dent"/>
        </character>
        <actor>      
            <Actor firstName="Simon" lastName="Jones"/>
        </actor>
    <properties>
</HBox>
```

is equivalent to

```
Actor actor = new Actor();
actor.setFirstName("Simon");
actor.setLastName("Jones");
HBox hbox = new HBox();
hbox.getProperties().put("character", "Arthur Dent");
hbox.getProperties().put("actor", actor);
```